# Can't update product / Unique constraint violation

Tags: magento2, product, upgrade

Since migration, to Magento 2.3 i can't save any products.

Exception.log reports (when i try to update in default scope) :

```
[2019-03-21 17:29:07] main.CRITICAL: Unique constraint violation found {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\AlreadyExistsException(code: 0): Unique constraint violation found at /home/mage4dalvin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Update.php:121, Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\DuplicateException(code: 1062): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '6-0-2-960.0000-0' for key 'UNQ_E8AB433B9ACB00343ABB312AD2FAB087', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` (`entity_id`, `all_groups`, `customer_group_id`, `qty`, `value`, `website_id`, `percentage_value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) at /home/mage4dalvin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:588, Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '6-0-2-960.0000-0' for key 'UNQ_E8AB433B9ACB00343ABB312AD2FAB087', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` (`entity_id`, `all_groups`, `customer_group_id`, `qty`, `value`, `website_id`, `percentage_value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) at /home/mage4dalvin/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '6-0-2-960.0000-0' for key 'UNQ_E8AB433B9ACB00343ABB312AD2FAB087' at /home/mage4dalvin/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []
```

AND (When i try to update in Store View Scope)

```
[2019-03-21 17:29:31] main.CRITICAL: Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/mage4dalvin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Option.php on line 175 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/mage4dalvin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Option.php on line 175 at /home/mage4dalvin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
```

All ideas are welcome.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you got the soln? actualy i am getting the same error.

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your database, search **catalog_product_entity_tier_price** table, find **entity_id = 6** , delete this and try update product again

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have try to trucate table, without result. For example when i create a new product, and i save it at the first time, no problem, if i would update after, i've got the same issue for any product.

Answer (score 0):

If it is configurable product, make sure all of it's simple products have the same attribute set as parent.